# why does rate determining step lead to these inequality relations?

Tags: kinetics

[image]
Here, the rate expression for the mechanism (i) is below:

$$rate = \frac{K_1^2k_2k_3[H^+][A]^2}{k_{-2}+K_1k_3[A]}$$

and for (ii),
$$rate = \frac{K_1k_2k_3[H^+][A]^2}{k_{-2}[H^+]+k_3[A]}$$

I was asked to show that the two sequences are kinetically distinguishable when the final step (i.e., C-C bond formation) is rate- limiting. The solution key says the final step being rate-limiting leads to the below expression. The rest is just some algebraic calculations which I don’t have a problem with, but I don’t understand how the below relationships are derived from the information on the rate-determining step. Could somebody kindly explain in details?

For (i),
$$K_1k_3[A] << K_{-2}$$

For (ii),
$$k_{-2}[H^+] >> k_3[A]$$

Comment: There is an error in the last row of the schema. Both neutral and protonated acetaldehyde are labeled the same and both reactions are assigned the same kinetic constant k3.

Comment: my bad, I have edited it. However, the question says that the last step's kinetic constant are both K3.

Comment: But they cannot be numerically the same.

Comment: When $k_3$ is v.v small wrt other constants then the limits shown apply, then the two schemes are distinguishable, but they are anyway so I don't see the point of the question.